# Multi-class multi-label classification in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-2

I am trying to train a multi-task multi-label classifier using Keras. The output layer is a fork of two outputs. The task of each output layer is to predict the categories of its task. The y vectors are OneHot encoded.

[image: Final output layer]

I am using a custom generator for my data that yields the `y` arrays in a list to the `fit_generator` function

I am using a `categorigal_crossentropy` loss function at each layer

```python
fork1.compile(loss={'O1': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'O2': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The problem: The loss doesn't decrease with this setup. However, if I train each task separately, I have low loss and high accuracy. So what could be the problem ?

Comment: can you share more code, like how you are calling `model.fit` and how you are creating fork1,2?

Answer (score 2):

To perform **multilabel categorical classification** (where each sample can have several classes), end your stack of layers with a Dense layer with a number of units equal to the number of classes and a sigmoid activation, and use binary_crossentropy as the loss. Your targets should be k-hot encoded.

Regarding the multi-output model, training such a model requires the ability to **specify different loss functions for different heads of the network requiring a different training procedure.**

You should provide more info in order to give a clear indication of what you want to achieve.